# Empty webView after several pages loaded in JB and above

Tags: android, webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am using a webView to display some contents in my android app:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
webView.loadData(result.getHtmlContent(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8");
```

This works perfectly in ICS and below, yet in JB and above the pages load correctly the first times (from two to five/six times generally). After that, the webView appears blank. Even after debugging, the code seems to run normally, it's just not displayed. The only way to see the page is to terminate the app and restart it, and it happens again.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the `webView.loadUrl("about:blank")` immediately before the `loadData` call? Does it help if you remove the `about:blank` load?

Also, 'not displayed' is pretty vague - is the content loaded but not rendering or does the page not get navigated to? Check what URLs your're getting from the `WebViewClient.onPageStarted`/`onPageFinished` callbacks. It might help if you call `loadData` from `onPageFinished` if url == "about:blank" if this is a navigation issue.

Comment: marcin.kosiba, I have removed webView.loadUrl("about:blank"), yet there is no difference. What I meant about not displayed is that the webview is there, it's just blank, after the loading seems to have happened correctly.

Comment: @Rahl_Pryde - have you checked the onPageStarted/Finished/onReceivedError callbacks? Have you looked at the logcat output?

Comment: you're right. logging the webViewClient methods I see that when the page is not displayed, the method onPageStarted is not even called. Yet debugging I see that the content that should be displayed is correct.

Comment: @Rahl_Pryde - One thing you could try is switching to loadDataWithBaseURL

Comment: actually, I originally found the error using loadDataWithBaseURL, after that I switched to loadData because I thought the problem was there, but the result is the same.

Comment: @Rahl_Pryde - any chance you could share code + APK that contain a repro? Doesn't have to be your app, just a stripped version that shows the problem.

Comment: sorry, but I can't share more than I have, the code doesn't belong to be but to my employer... Still, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
webView.loadData(htmlContent, "text/html; charset=UTF-8",null);
```

for the versions greater than GINGERBREAD_MR1.

And

```
webViewLivraison.loadDataWithBaseURL("",htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

for the versions GINGERBREAD_MR1 and below. And its working fine for me.

Try this and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be happening still.

Answer (score 0):

Try this clear for every time before the page load also try to clear the caches if u need.

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient());
        webView.clearView();
         // add if u need
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.loadData(result.getHtmlContent(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are possible reasons causing "WebView goes blank after finish loading page":

1. If your WebView part defined in the layout xml file has dimensions like

   ```
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   ```

   or

   ```
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ```

Then after the page is loaded, the content is defined and WebView tries to "wrap" it, thus in some cases reduces the view's dimensions into 0dp and make your WebView invisible.
Solution: change all those into fill_parent

```
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

2. This may be caused by an SSL certification error. Try this:

```
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed();
}
```